# Why don't my two columns fill up top column?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am learning to create a responsive website and have following problem:
I have two columns (col-6) that need to fill up an upper column (col-9). Col-9 is centered and I need two columns (col-6) inside col-9.
HTML:

```
<div class="row col-12 troeven-0"> 
<div class="col-container col-9 col-center-block troeven-1"> 
<div class="colom col-6 goedkoop">
 <h2 class="troeven">
   GOEDKOOP
 </h2>
 <img src="goedkoop.jpg" width="400" height="155" alt="goedkoop" />
 </div>
  <div class="colom col-6 responsive">
 <h2 class="troeven">
   RESPONSIVE
  </h2>
 <img src="goedkoop.jpg" width="400" height="155" alt="goedkoop" />
 </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/* For desktop: op PC (of bij een minimum van 768px hebben alle kolommen onderstaande breedte*/
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}
}

.troeven-0 {
 height: auto;
 }

 .troeven-1 {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
   }

 .goedkoop {
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  background: red;
   }

 .responsive {
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  background: blue;
  }
```

Are there too many columns inside eachother or a column too less? Greatly appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap for making a webpage responsive. In Bootstrap the code will be like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h2 class="troeven">
                            GOEDKOOP
                        </h2>
                        <img src="goedkoop.jpg" width="400" height="155" alt="goedkoop"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h2 class="troeven">
                            RESPONSIVE
                        </h2>
                        <img src="goedkoop.jpg" width="400" height="155" alt="goedkoop"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can find a lot of useful things about page grid and making responsive webpage in by Bootstrap in [this link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Comment: Thanks but I don't use Bootstrap atm. Still learning so trying to begin with the basic. 
Here you can see the problem: berlamo.be. The red block responds perfectly with the parent (col-9) but the blue block stops being responsive when the screen is being stretched. Hopefully you can see the problem..

Comment: I found the problem: my col-container was wrongly put. Stupid mistake by me, thanks anyway for the help all!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the columns to fill up the width of the outer column?

```
  .goedkoop {
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    background: red;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
 }

 .responsive {
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    background: blue;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Adding margin: auto; and text-align: center; should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't do the trick... Here you can see the problem: http://berlamo.be/. The red block responds perfectly with the parent (col-9) but the blue block stops being responsive when the screen is being stretched. Hopefully you can see the problem...

Comment: I found the problem: my col-container was wrongly put. Stupid mistake by me, thanks anyway for the help all!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: my col-container was wrongly put. Stupid mistake by me, thanks anyway for the help all!